# pass array to oracle procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to send two arrays form java to oracle stored procedures.
The first Array is array of strings and the second is array of chars 
how can I make this??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it.

The following script sets up a table, a type and a stored procedure in the database.  The procedure takes a parameter of the array type and inserts each row of the array into the table:

```
CREATE TABLE strings (s VARCHAR(4000));

CREATE TYPE t_varchar2_array AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_array_test(
    p_strings      t_varchar2_array
)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..p_strings.COUNT
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO strings (s) VALUES (p_strings(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The Java code then demonstrates passing an array into this stored procedure:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.sql.*;

public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "user", "pass");

        CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN p_array_test(?); END;");

        // The first parameter here should be the name of the array type.
        // It's been capitalised here since I created it without using
        // double quotes.
        ArrayDescriptor arrDesc =
            ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("T_VARCHAR2_ARRAY", conn);

        String[] data = { "one", "two", "three" };
        Array array = new ARRAY(arrDesc, conn, data);
        stmt.setArray(1, array);
        stmt.execute();

        conn.commit();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

If you run the SQL script and then the Java class, and then query the table `strings`, you should find that all of the data has been inserted into the table.

When you say 'an array of chars',  I'm guessing that you mean an array of Java `char`s.  If I've guessed right, then I think you'd be best off converting the `char`s to `String`s and then using the same approach as above.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with multidimensional arrays? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045019/reading-an-oracle-nested-table-type-using-jdbc-for-an-oracle-type-with-more-than

Comment: I have copy/paste your entire solution - resulting in table "strings" containing three (null) values... using oracle 9i as well as 10g and all available jdbc drivers - result is the same. oracle.sql.ARRAY is empty when it is created in java - I'm trying to find solution, but no luck so far :( it is same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998299/oracle-array-filled-with-null-data-in-java

Comment: @Luke Woodward: I upvoted you. Can you extend a bit for how to pass an arraylist toa function. The function in the database is not created by me and I need to pass 2 arraylists.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: no, I don't see why I should.  Are you not aware of the `toArray()` method on an ArrayList?

Answer (score 4):

Look here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraarr.htm#i1058512

and here is my short example:

1) on database

```
SQL> create or replace type string_array as table of varchar2(100);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace function to_string(p_array in string_array) return varchar2
  2  as
  3     l_string varchar2(32767);
  4     i binary_integer;
  5  begin
  6     i := p_array.first();
  7     while i is not null loop
  8        l_string := l_string || p_array(i) || ';';
  9        i := p_array.next(i);
 10     end loop;
 11     l_string := rtrim(l_string, ';');
 12     return l_string;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

2) in java

```
public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
        OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(...);

        String[] elements = {"abc", "def", "geh"};
        ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("STRING_ARRAY", connection);
        ARRAY array = new ARRAY(descriptor, connection, elements);

        OracleCallableStatement stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("{? = call to_string(?)}");
        stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.setARRAY(2, array);
        stmt.execute();

        String result = stmt.getString(1);
        System.out.println("to_string returned: " + result);
    }
}
```

seems to work: output says

```
to_string returned: abc;def;geh
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `ArrayDescriptor` is deprecated since 12c, it should not be used anymore.
Here's a code sniplet that worked for me in 12c:

```
            Array array = ((OracleConnection) connection).createOracleArray("T_VARCHAR2_ARRAY", data);
            CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{call p_array_test(?)}");
            statement.setArray(1, array);
            statement.execute();
```

Comment: Sometimes we can't just cast the Connection. We have to unwrap it, `getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Regex solve

```
select * from table_a  a where a.col in (select   regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;)
```

Comment: Are you suggesting converting the array to a comma-seperated `String` and passing it to a procedure expecting a `varchar2`; then decomposing it back to its elements? That seems messy, can hit the 32k size limit, and will break (possibly silently) if any of the values already contain a comma...

Answer (score 0):

PeudoCode for the same how I achieved.

```
    # 1.You will require a structDescriptor object for an object equivalent in pl sql like :

    StructDescriptor structDes= new StructDescriptor("<schemaname in caps>.<sql_object_name>", connectionObject);

    # 2. You will need to pass one object values such name, class, id to an object array in order and accordance to 'sql_object_name' object. 

    For exmaple:
    STRUCT[] structArray=new STRUCT[<ListObj>.size()];
    int index=0;
    for (a in ListObj){

    Object[] object=new Object[]{a.getName(),a.getId()};
    STRUCT struct=new STRUCT(structDes ,connectionObject,object);
               structArray[index]=struct;
               index++;

    }

    ArrayDescriptor arrayDes=ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
        "<Schema name>.<table object from sql>", connectionObject);

    ARRAY array=new ARRAY(arrayDes,connectionObject, structArray);

   then pass it to proc 

   .declareParameters(
   new SqlInOutParameter("<parameter to proc name>",OracleTypes.ARRAY,"
   <schema name>.<sql_array_or_table_obj>"))

   like 
   Hashmap<String, Object> map= new HashMap<>();
   map.put("<parameter to proc name>",array);
   psStatement.execute(map);
```

Hope it helps. This sequence may vary as per requirement and type of sql database used, but base is same.

I have copied this answer from one of my other answers.

[Pass array as input parameter to an oracle stored procedure using simple jdbc call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655331/pass-array-as-input-parameter-to-an-oracle-stored-procedure-using-simple-jdbc-ca/49854059#49854059)

Answer (score 0):

The new approach is to unwrap the `OracleConnection` and then use `createOracleArray`.

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
Array array = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("REF_TYPE_ARRAY", referralTypeId);

inputParameters.put("itemIds", array);
```

Also see: [How to create an oracle.sql.ARRAY object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878735/how-to-create-an-oracle-sql-array-object/76571542#76571542)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Oracle Types to map Java objects to Oracle.  Also, there's Spring JDBC utilities.