# pass object from Java to Oracle procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, object

To pass an array to oracle procedure we use `ArrayDiscriptor` and 
 `ARRAY`  objects. What objects do I have to use to pass an object to 
a stored procedure?

Comment: Is the Oracle procedure written in PL/SQL or Java?

Comment: Orcale procedure written in PL/SQL .

Comment: Dupe - [Pass array to Oracle Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198856/pass-array-to-oracle-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArrayDesciptor and ARRAY classes (as well as StructDescriptor and STRUCT) map to Oracle TYPES - i.e. objects created something like...

```
create type my_obj as object( id varchar2(x), etc );
```

If you have access to the java, you should be able to see where the ArrayDescriptor is constructed and get the database type name from that.

You can use these oracle types as parameters to functions and procedures.