# Pass array as input parameter to an oracle stored procedure using simple jdbc call

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

Here is my oracle procedure specifications

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_RE_FI AS

  PROCEDURE PRC_RE_FI_DETAILS(P_FAN_NO       IN VARCHAR2,
                              P_REF_ID       IN TY_APP_REF_ID,
                              P_COMMENTS     IN VARCHAR2,
                              P_BILLING_FLAG IN VARCHAR2,
                              P_STATUS       OUT VARCHAR2);
END PKG_RE_FI;
```

TY_APP_REF_ID is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ty_app_REF_ID as varray(500) of obj_array_ref_id

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_array_ref_id  AS OBJECT(
app_ref_id VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

I am using Spring JDBC Framework(SimpleJdbcCall object) to execute above procedure. Below is the code snippet in which i have declared

```
      this.reFIJdbcCall =  new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withCatalogName("PKG_RE_FI").
              withProcedureName("PRC_RE_FI_DETAILS").declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_FAN_NO", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("P_REF_ID", Types.ARRAY),
                        new SqlParameter("P_COMMENTS", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("P_BILLING_FLAG", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlOutParameter("P_STATUS", Types.VARCHAR)
              );
```

How should i pass array to the

```
new SqlParameter("P_REF_ID", Types.ARRAY),
```

to MapSqlParameterSource

```
 MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PeudoCode for the same how I achieved.

```
    # 1.You will require a structDescriptor object for an object equivalent in pl sql like :

    StructDescriptor structDes= new StructDescriptor("<schemaname in caps>.<sql_object_name>", connectionObject);

    # 2. You will need to pass one object values such name, class, id to an object array in order and accordance to 'sql_object_name' object. 

    For exmaple:
    STRUCT[] structArray=new STRUCT[<ListObj>.size()];
    int index=0;
    for (a in ListObj){

    Object[] object=new Object[]{a.getName(),a.getId()};
    STRUCT struct=new STRUCT(structDes ,connectionObject,object);
               structArray[index]=struct;
               index++;

    }

    ArrayDescriptor arrayDes=ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
        "<Schema name>.<table object from sql>", connectionObject);

    ARRAY array=new ARRAY(arrayDes,connectionObject, structArray);

   then pass it to proc 

   .declareParameters(
   new SqlInOutParameter("<parameter to proc name>",OracleTypes.ARRAY,"
   <schema name>.<sql_array_or_table_obj>"))

   like 
   Hashmap<String, Object> map= new HashMap<>();
   map.put("<parameter to proc name>",array);
   psStatement.execute(map);
```

Hope it helps. This sequence may vary as per requirement and type of sql database used, but base is same.

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/) project has some support that makes this easier. Take a look at the [reference manual for passing in an Oracle ARRAY type](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html#d0e2387).

Comment: Hi.. In my case there are few more input parameters along with the array mentioned. How will the same be Done ?